# How to get primary key columns out of a TSqlObject instance?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac, dac

I'm trying to get the primary key columns out of a `TSqlObject` instance in the following manner:

```
var constraint = table.GetReferenced(ModelSchema.PrimaryKeyConstraint, DacQueryScopes.All);
```

Of course this doesn't work, as the `GetReferenced` method expects an instance of `ModelRelationshipClass` instance.

So how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code to get the PK constraint given a table would look a bit like this:

```
private static TSqlObject GetPrimaryKeyConstraint(TSqlObject table)
{
    IEnumerable<TSqlObject> constraints = table.GetReferencing(PrimaryKeyConstraint.Host, DacQueryScopes.UserDefined);
    return constraints.First();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at this:

https://github.com/Microsoft/DACExtensions/tree/master/DacFxStronglyTypedModel

You can get what you want without having to use the enumeration / relationship model :)